# User Agent is different when re-sizing image before upload

Tags: javascript, file-upload, swfupload

Swfupload normally sends `"Shockwave Flash"` as user agent when uploading files using `SWFUpload.startUpload`. However, when I use `SWFUpload.startResizedUploadimage` in order to resize before uploading, it sends `"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30"` as user agent.

Do you know why?

I am using swfupload v250Beta3.

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably ask this in the Swfupload forums

Comment: @epascarello I'd like to understand how it works in order to work around it. It's better to understand first.
@Pumbaa80 sorry but I don't get you. Why my question shouldn't be at SO under the swfupload tag? Why a forum is more suitable?